# Touchpad scrolling

Tags: gnome, touchpad, synaptics, scrolling

Just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu.

I wonder if it's possible to enable two fingers and edge scrolling, both??? I think I had this on Xubuntu. BTW, I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with Gnome 3 installed.

Comment: follow this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now I must say I got used to these ubuntu limitations. I just use two finger scrolling. But when I followed the link shantanu provided, the long gone desire was back! And I successfully set it up. I describe how so it will be all at one place.

First create a sh with the needed command:

```
echo "synclient VertEdgeScroll=1 VertTwoFingerScroll=1" > /home/user/touchpad_settings_upd.sh
```

Set it as executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/user/touchpad_settings_upd.sh
```

Tell ubuntu to run this file every time GUI starts:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command "/home/user/touchpad_settings_upd.sh"
```

Works nice, so I think I'll stick with this from now...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way to do this is by using dconf-editor:

- Open Terminal
- Type in *dconf-editor* and hit Enter
- Now go to **org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>touchpad** and try **scroll-method**

Here's a screenshot of dconf-editor:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## New / Ubuntu / GUI Way

1. Click the **Cog** (session menu) on top right corner
2. Click the menu item **System Settings...**
3. Click **Mouse & Touchpad** icon in **Hardware** section
4. Click / Disable **Two finger scroll**, which instantly result in
   enabling **Edge scrolling** instead