# Enable BOTH edge scrolling and two-finger scrolling for touchpad

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

On Ubuntu, I can choose between **Edge scrolling**, and **Two-finger scrolling**. But it's a radio button, so I have to choose between one and the other.

But is there any way to enable them **both at the same time**? Is this limitation because of the config GUI only?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### To enable this permanently:

Create a file with the commands in [mikewhatever answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/248304/169736):

```
echo synclient VertEdgeScroll=1 >> ~/.config/scroll-touchpad
echo synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1 >> ~/.config/scroll-touchpad
```

We make it executable, and protect it from being deleted:

```
chmod +x ~/.config/scroll-touchpad
chmod -w ~/.config/scroll-touchpad
```

The we add to our gconf settings this file:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command '"'$HOME'/.config/scroll-touchpad"'
```

Now you can restart Gnome, log out and in, etc. and your preferences will persist.

Based on [Nahuel answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/156545/169736)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1` to enable vertical edge scrolling,

or `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1` for two finger scrolling.

Just copy/paste a command into a terminal window, and hit Enter.

So to have both just paste:

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Comment: The commands are **not persistent**, it seems that this setting is being reset every time after I suspend and resume my laptop, and also when I reboot it, so I need to enter those commands again every time.

Comment: You are right, touchpad settings are reset on login by gnome-settings-daemon. You can try adapting [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/156545/20054) to your case. The command you'd use would be `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1 VertTwoFingerScroll=1`, or the two commands, as posted above, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can also add the command to the startup process

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that your computer is recognizing your touchpad as a mouse.  Run this command and insure the touch pad is seen as "EPTS/2", not "PS/2".

```
xinput list
```

The solution is found at:

https://superuser.com/questions/721417/elantech-touchpad-recognized-as-ps-2-mouse-ubuntu-13-10