# Touchpad sometimes not working after click on Thinkpad T440s

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, thinkpad

I have brought a Thinkpad T440s from Lenovo and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it. It works good, but there is one big issue: Often the mouse freezes after a click for a few seconds and sometimes the mouse freezes forever until I remove the psmouse module and re-add it:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

After that the touchpad starts working again normally, if it is still frozen I have to reboot the laptop. I am not sure, but could that be a problem with the driver? Here is interesting part of the dmesg output:

```
[  531.369723] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[  531.386334] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[  531.388140] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[  531.396685] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[  531.399687] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[  531.400798] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[  531.407985] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[  920.895669] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[  920.908302] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 1116.953171] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[ 1117.204120] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1117.205379] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1117.206550] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1117.207728] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1117.208919] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1117.208929] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
[ 1173.743451] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[ 1173.974331] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[ 1173.975528] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1173.976673] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1173.977828] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1173.979044] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1173.979054] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
[ 1231.478893] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.
[ 1308.995128] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[ 1457.439552] psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
[ 1820.123546] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[ 1820.124699] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1820.125855] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1820.127023] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1820.128171] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 1820.128182] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware issue, and should be reproducible in other operating systems (like Windows 7). The Windows 8 drivers apparently have some sort of workaround (maybe faster reconnecting or ignoring of these error conditions). The issue (at least in my case) is easy to fix - the touchpad cable moves around and becomes disconnected when I press the touchpad button - you should be able to confirm this by determine if you only see the errors shown above when you push the touchpad down.

The solution is to either have Lenovo replace the touchpad, or fix it yourself. In my case, I rerouted the touchpad cable under the battery in a manner such that when I push the touchpad the cable does not come loose. This took only a few minutes, so if you've already opened the bottom of your laptop you probably don't have anything to lose.

Comment: I also had this issue with a Thinkpad t440s under Ubuntu 13.10 (but not under Windows 8) and as per Andrew's answer, although I thought it was a bug, it was actually a hardware fault. The best way to confirm it is to boot into Windows 7 where the problem is also easy to replicate.  Windows 8 obviously copes with bad bytes from the trackpad in a different way.  Lenovo replaced my keyboard bezel under warranty (the bit that contains the trackpad) and the problem has been solved.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thank you! I installed Windows 8 and was also able to reproduce this problem there. It also occured in the Windows installation GUI... I sended the laptop to Lenovo. I have been waiting for 4 weeks now and yesterday I got the laptop back. The error still exists and they didn't do anything :-(. Today I went to the shop where I bought it. They have never seen this issue before but they will send the machine back to Lenovo again. Maybe I have more luck this time... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that it is a hardware issue. Attempts to reroute the touchpad cable weren't successful. The touchpad exchange fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the indicator-cpufreq package (`sudo apt-get install
indicator-cpufreq`) than reboot. It has solved the problem for me.

See this [mailing](https://lists.launchpad.net/kernel-packages/msg17719.html).

Comment: I can definitely say that this is  not a solution, at least in my case. New Yoga 12, with touchscreen and everything, and has to be replaced after just 2 weeks? I guess my last ThinkPad.

Answer (score 0):

A fix working for me is given here: [Touchpad stopped working out of the blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367701/touchpad-stopped-working-out-of-the-blue)

Create a configuration file for the touchpad:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf
```

Add this to the file:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

SAVE file.

REBOOT

This is on a T440s