# After using Intel Graphics Installer my touchpad no longer works

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, intel-graphics, trackpad

I am still able to use a mouse however, but the touchpad will not respond. Toggling the on/off button for the trackpad on my keyboard does not change anything. I haven't seen anything that permanently fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently the Intel Graphics Installer automatically uninstalled the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Reinstalling this package should re-enable your touchpad.

Refer to this post: [Touchpad stopped working out of the blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367701/touchpad-stopped-working-out-of-the-blue/369229#369229)

Comment: Does it uninstall any other packages or programs that I should want to keep asides from the trackpad?

Answer (score 0):

Try switch back to packages on the main repos rather than the Intel repos.

To do this, follow the instructions at http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/how-to-downgrade-proposed-repository.html

Just change saucy to trusty, and consider the proposed repo to be the Intel repo [which lives in other software]

If you need any help, say so in the comments of this answer