# ELAN touchpad suddenly stopped working, worked the day before

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Installed 16.04 fresh on a new drive yesterday. Everything worked fine, from installation to normal usage, even the touchpad with gestures and all. Today I was trying to boot a live USB with another distro (Backbox) to install alongside Xenial, but had some problems due to graphics and/or touchpad drivers missing.

After that, suddenly the touchpad *stopped working in Ubuntu as well*, not even a cursor. A USB mouse works. I've tried every "solution" Google can find, I think, including:

- install/reinstall `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
- `modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps`
- checking `dconf` (as in the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/369229/40894)
- `Fn` key + `F10` (toggle touchpad) -> touchpad is not even available in System Settings
- Adding `i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop` to grub boot options (https://askubuntu.com/a/528429/40894)
- Forcing insecure boot (`sudo mokutil --enable-validation`) -> this made the touchpad work only as a PS/2 mouse (for a while)

Even a newly downloaded ISO (today) won't boot the installation program with touchpad recognised. Why would it work yesterday and this morning and suddenly stop working? I'm hesitant to file a bug report since I don't know yet why it just stopped working.

The system setup:

- XMG C404 (Gigabyte P34Gv2 motherboard)
- ELAN touchpad
- Nvidia GTX 860M
- Dual-booting Windows 10 (separate drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's a hardware problem. The same issues have shown even when booted in Windows and charger connected.