# Touchpad suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xorg, firefox, touchpad, acer

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Acer Swift 3. This occurred when my system froze because of Mozilla Firefox and I forced restarted the laptop. Since then my touchpad stopped working. I tried to reinstall `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` but nothing worked. Please help me.

Comment: See [Touchpad stopped working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235067/348964)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Touchpad stopped working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235067/touchpad-stopped-working-20-04)