# Touchpad cannot move the cursor

Tags: drivers, 20.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

Suddenly I cannot move the cursor using touchpad, however, the clicking is ok (left+right click)

I have tried the following:

1. Fn+F10 to turn on my touchpad
2. Turn on touchpad in Mouse&Touchpad setting
3. 

```
>>xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx wireless dongle Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx wireless dongle Consumer Control    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Mouse               id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Touchpad            id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>> xinput enable 19
>> xinput enable 20
>> xinput list-props 19
Device 'MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Mouse':
    Device Enabled (115):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (117): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (253):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (254):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (255):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (256):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (257):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (258): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (259): 3
    libinput Accel Speed (262): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (263): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (264):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (265):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (266):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (267): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (268): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (238): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (239):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (240):    0, 0
    Device Node (241):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (242):    1739, 32552
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (269):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (270):   1
```

I also tried reinstalling, but the cursor doesn't move even during the installation.

Any idea?

UPDATE: This problem is specific to Lenovo Legion 5 laptop. I found a workaround solution here:
https://www.linux.org/threads/lenovo-legion-5-touchpad.29536/page-2#post-104544

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1271982/1013762

Simply do:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

More details provided in the answer.

Comment: It is very unlikely.