# Ubuntu 22.04 no longer recognizing trackpad or nub

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 22.04, thinkpad

I'm running a relatively new (<1 week old) install of 22.04 on a Thinkpad E14 (also relatively recently purchased, about a month ago). After doing some day-to-day tasks for about a week without rebooting, I had to reboot the machine because of a `usermod -aG docker`.

Unfortunately, upon reboot, the trackpad and nub mouse built into the laptop no longer seem to work. Stranger still, the touch screen is completely responsive and is fully functional. External USB mice are recognized as usual. I haven't got a Bluetooth mouse on hand to test that.

I've done some digging around the internet about this issue, but haven't been able to make much headway; most of the official docs outline how to generate a bug report for the Wayland team.

The only thing that I believe may have caused this issue in the <1 week since the reinstall was running `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, though I made sure that none of the upgraded packages were (at least obviously) related to Wayland, `libva`, `libinput`, or even Synaptics.

Following instructions provided at [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235067/touchpad-stopped-working-20-04), I can confirm that using `rmmod`-`modprobe` has no effect besides causing the pointer to show up (and disappear again as soon as the touchscreen is used), and the trackpad and nub *do not* work in the graphical BIOS. There are also no options to select a graphics mode in this laptop's BIOS.

I'd be happy to provide diagnostics upon requests, but as I'm unfamiliar with window managers and input drivers, I'll wait for suggestions from the comments if this is necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved! Oddly enough, this appears to have been caused by a specific grub setting. In `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This causes a fallback to an older version of cgroups. I don't fully understand why this affects trackpad drivers, but bisect-style testing confirms that this is the culprit.

A solution is to either remove this option, or if it's preferred on, to use the `tlp-rdw` package from the `linrunner/tlp` PPA (from [this](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) project).

Comment: Trying to solve this with tlp-rdw is complete nonsense. I suggest you remove that from your post.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't make sense, but testing shows that this solved the issue. Going off your name it looks like you might be the author, so if you have other suggestions, please go ahead and post them.