# Rescuing mouse/trackpad/keyboard control on a Lenovo P50

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

### History

- Ubuntu Mate, 20.04 on a Lenovo P50. All fine until yesterday.
- Automatic updates (Oct. 2021) broke the trackpad.
- I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271982/89062). They didn't work. They also aren't supposed to be permanent, so hopefully no worries --- but I mention it in case this did change something permanently.
- I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235083/89062), reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. This *may* have worked. In any case, the touchpad was *partially* working after a reboot.

### Problems

- After this "fix", "tap to click" was re-enabled, and was way too sensitive. The laptop was unusable: click would trigger while typing causing the cursor to jump randomly.
- I tried to disable "tap to click", but the trackpad control panel no longer exists.
- To fix this, I tried to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/783734/89062). However, if followed literally, **the indicated steps break all input devices**

***So! I how have a Lenovo P50 laptop***

- With no working trackpad or keyboard
- Which won't respond to an external mouse or keyboard
- Which doesn't have a SSH server running so I can't remote into it

**How does one get this machine working again, and also: how does one resolve the original issues with the trackpad that made the machine unusable?**

Sorry for the lack of system configuration information, I can't run any commands on the machine so I can't provide their outputs ( :

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it:

1. Reboot machine; Hold `esc` while booting to get the grub menu to appear.
2. In my case keyboard navigation of the grub menu didn't seem to work at first --- but actually was just slow. I had to wait a second to see a response after each key press.
3. Use the up/down arrows to select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and press `enter`. On my machine, this led to an empty screen. It's *supposed* to show a list of previously installed kernels, along with some options to boot into a "recovery mode".
4. Despite the "invisible grub" issue, I pressed the down arrow several times, then "enter". This loaded the recovery mode menu (with some garbled text overlaid).
5. Use the arrow keys to select `root: Drop to root shell prompt`
6. Run apt-get install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`
7. Run `rebooot now`

After performing these steps, the trackpad worked and the trackpad control center reappeared. I was able to select "disable touchpad while typing" to resolve the original issue.