# Lenovo trackpoint stops working randomly

Tags: mouse, lenovo, trackpoint

The trackpoint and associated mouse buttons recently stopped working on my Lenovo P50 laptop. The recent automatic updates (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, October 2021) played [havoc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367281/rescuing-mouse-trackpad-keyboard-control-on-a-lenovo-p50) with the trackpad, but that was fixed by re-installing `libinput` and `synapics`. Unfortunately, this did not fix the trackpoint and its associated mouse buttons.

I've searched stack exchange, and existing knowledge of this is pretty old (relating to  bugs from a few years ago), or relating to different problems (intermittent trackpoint failure or issues with the trackpad, not trackpoint).

Would anyone happen to know if there is a standard way to fix this? Perhaps I missed something.

#### Edit:

To add to the weirdness, the trackpoint works again after resuming from *suspend*. However, it will randomly stop working some minutes later.

#### Edit 2:

Ultimately, this was never resolved. The motherboard of the Lenovo P50 eventually failed, rendering the question irrelevant. That said, here is what I know.

I replaced the P50 with a P51. This is the next iteration, but is parts-compatible with P50 in terms of keyboard, trackpad, trackpoint, and the arrangement of RAM and SSD/HDD slots.

The new machine had the following configuration

```
Bios version is N1UET80W (1.54)
Bios Date is 2020-11-05
Embedded controller version N1UHT27W (1.10)
ME Firware Version 11.8.80.3746
Machine Type model 20HJS4T300
Sysunit serial PF0Y1SJT
Sysboard serial L1HF83L00D5
```

The trackpad and trackpoint work with a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS.
This points weakly to one of the following scenarios:

- Sporadic trackpad/trackpoint failures are symptomatic of a pre-fail state for the system mainbord.
- There is a driver issue with the chipsets used in the Lenovo P50, which does not affect those used by the P51. *This is somewhat unlikely as the trackpoint uses the same parts, but perhaps some part of the main-board chipset is relevant.*
- There is an issue with the BIOS that might be fixed by updating.
- There was a driver issue that has since been resolved as of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I don't have any help, but I'm having the same thing happen occasionally with both a T470s and T495s running Debian 11. I get this in kern.log when it happens:

`Jan 10 10:34:01 dragoncable kernel: [109592.227858] psmouse serio2: Mouse at rmi4-00.fn03/serio0/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.`
`Jan 10 10:34:03 dragoncable kernel: [109594.516833] psmouse serio2: failed to re-enable mouse on rmi4-00.fn03/serio0`
`Jan 10 10:34:03 dragoncable kernel: [109594.516836] psmouse serio2: resync failed, issuing reconnect request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a Synaptics trackpad driver. I downloaded the latest driver from
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/ - I also installed wine and when the mouse stopped working, I used wine to execute the *.exe  file. I then unplugged my mouse and plugged it back in. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue on a Lenovo x1 Tablet running Ubuntu 22.04, even with the after resuming temporary fix. I haven't figured out yet what might be the problem as it happens even on different kernel versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223509)

Comment: StackExchange rules say this "answer" should actually be a comment on the original question, but ... no harm done, really.