# Mousepad-specific settings missing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, settings

Recently, 2-finger scroll stopped working on my laptop. There may have been some minor updates applied beforehand, but nothing that had to do specifically with pointing devices. This is on a fairly fresh installation of Ubuntu as I was having unrelated issues and decided to start over with a clean slate. In the process of trying to fix the scrolling problem, I noticed that within `Settings > Mouse & Touchpad`, there are no mousepad-specific options like I know there were previously (I don't remember exactly what they said, I think I could pick between editing settings for my mouse and for my touchpad).
I've tried the commands listed below, but the issue persists.

```
sudo apt remove gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

I've also followed the answers to a very similar question here: [Mouse & Touchpad Separate Settings Missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783396/mouse-touchpad-separate-settings-missing).
However, none of these worked either, and as it was both several years and several versions of Ubuntu ago, maybe some things have changed.
If anyone has a solution to the overarching 2-finger scroll issue, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

I've listed the output of `xinput` and `xinput list-props 19` below. The touchpad is **ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Mouse** at ID 19.

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade Keyboard                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Mouse               id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Gaming Mouse                          id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat           id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat           id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade Keyboard                id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Gaming Mouse                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ xinput list-props 19
Device 'ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Mouse':
    Device Enabled (204):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (206): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (339):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (340):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (341):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (342):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (343):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (344): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (345): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (346):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (347):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (350): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (351): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (352):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (353):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (354):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (355): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (356): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (324): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (325):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (326):    0, 0
    Device Node (327):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (328):    1267, 12454
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (357):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (358):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (359):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (360):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (361):    1
```

Thanks in advance!