# Enable both: two finger scrolling and edge scrolling permanently

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

Recently, I have upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10. First, I found problem in edge scrolling. After surfing in net about the problem I came to know that Ubuntu 13.10 has default two-finger scroll option enabled in Mouse and Touchpad setting. After unchecking two-finger scroll edge scrolling was enabled.

In windows, I have used both feature. How can I use both two finger scrolling and edge scrolling in Ubuntu 13.10 permanently  so that the setting won't reset even after I restart, shutdown or suspend my laptop?

Comment: @user212656 Actually, there is a "proper answer" on that question; it has 6 upvotes and is the accepted answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: @searchfgold6789 Yes, I have first searched for solution and then only I posted this. 
I viewed this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad)
I found yesterday only permanent solution was provided.

Comment: go to dconf-editor and find the settings daemon. you can find the touchpad in the peripherals dialog.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/248304/147044), you can enable both two finger scrolling and edge scrolling using the following commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

The problem is that these commands are not persistent after a system restart. To prevent this, let's put them to run at start up.

First, make a new small bash script called `scrolling` with the following code inside:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Save it in your `~/bin` directory, and don't forget to make it executable using the following command in terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/scrolling
```

Second, search for **Startup Applications** in **Dash**, and open it:

[image: startup applications]

Then add the script `scrolling` to run at startup:

[image: startup applications]

Comment: how to enable natural scrolling for two finger scrolling only.

Comment: @Habi Well, go to **System Settings** -> **Mouse & Touchpad** and you will find those options there.

Comment: checking natural scrolling option there enables natural scrolling for both types of scrolling.
I want only and only two-finger scrolling to be "natural scrolling" enabled and edge scrolling to be "natural scrolling" disabled.

Comment: Radu, the man! Awesome!

Comment: it would be a little easier if you put that commmand (`synclient [option]`) on your `$HOME/.profile`, it wil run on every login

Comment: This only works if you have a touchpad made by Synaptics.