# How to enable natural scroll on two-finger scroll with command while normal scrolling for edge scrolling in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling

After getting both scroll enabled in Ubuntu 13.10. 
From following method:
[Enable both: two finger scrolling and edge scrolling permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372988/enable-both-two-finger-scrolling-and-edge-scrolling-in-ubuntu-13-10-permanantly)

I want natural scrolling enabled for two-finger scroll and normal scrolling for edge scroll?

I know it's possible. Since, I don't know how to enable natural scrolling in Ubuntu 13.10, it's being difficult for me to solve the problem.

You can view mentioned link too if you don't get what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for this problem.
Install if you haven't

> sudo apt-get install synclient

And next change "vertical scrolling delta" to negative value, like this

> synclient VertScrollDelta=-100

Done. You have natural scrolling everywhere.