# How to merge free space with filesystem partition?

Tags: disk, disk-management

[image: snapshot of my disk]

That's the layout of my disk. I want to merge free space to the primary partition without data loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, you can merge the `3.2gb` free space to your Ubuntu partition.

- For this you need a [**gparted-live-disk**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php).Because you cannot resize a mounted partition when the filesystem is mounted.
- Boot into gparted live disk
- Right Click on the **Extended partition** and select **Move/Resize** option, then add the unallocated **3.2 gb** space to it.
- Now the unallocated 3.2gb space comes under the extended partition.
- Then rightclick on your Ubuntu **ext4** partition and select **Move/Resize** option,now 3.2gb free space will be shown and you can add that.

Comment: Can you tell how to boot into gpareted live disk? I have install gparted but I can't click to Move/Resize option.

Comment: download gparted-live-disk iso file from the link above.Then use `unetbootin software` to make a usb bootable gparted disk.shutdown and change the boot order to usb in bios.And now you can booted into gparted live disk.

Comment: Ok, got it bro.

Comment: I have already done it. :)
@AvinashRaj
Can you check this question.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/373147/how-to-enable-natural-scroll-on-two-finger-scroll-with-command-while-normal-scro

Comment: Why not simply use the Ubunutu live media which already has gparted on it? And you should mention the length of time it will take and the risk of data loss when moving the partition to the left.

Comment: Oh yes @chaskes that's also good idea. Forgot about that
:)

Comment: thank you man !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case it is not possible to merge 3.2GB free space with your extended partition because it is in the beginning of your partition.

Comment: There must be some solution.

Comment: It's possible. It's just not a great idea.