# Synaptics Touchpad scroll not working

Tags: 14.04, xorg, dell, touchpad, synaptics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Studio 1557.
My synaptics touch pad is detected but the scroll functions are not working.
The scroll option in the GUI for the mouse and touch pad has disappeared.
I have tried reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package but receive the following error of Package 'xorg-input-abi-20' has no installation candidate.
Please advise for a solution.

[image: Mousepad GUI]

The following is the output and I am still unable to install the multi-touch package.

```
hmehra@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for hmehra: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Removed xserver-xorg-core

```
hmehra@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove xserver-xorg-core
[sudo] password for hmehra: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev
xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom
xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 28 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
After this operation, 11.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 411157 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-xorg (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion (2:1.7.7-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-ati (2:7.1.0-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse (2:13.0.0-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-mouse (2:1.8.1-makson1~raring3) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-mach64 (1:6.9.4-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-intel (3:2.21.4-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-evdev (2:2.7.3-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-wacom (2:0.20.0-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-cirrus (2:1.5.2-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-fbdev (2:0.4.3-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-mga (2:1.6.2-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-modesetting (1:0.6.0-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-neomagic (2:1.2.7-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (2:1.0.6-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-openchrome (2:0.3.1-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-qxl (1:0.1.0-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-r128 (1:6.9.1-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-radeon (2:7.1.0-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-s3 (2:0.6.5-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-savage (2:2.3.6-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-sis (2:0.10.7-makson1~raring2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-sisusb (2:0.9.6-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-tdfx (2:1.4.5-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-trident (2:1.3.6-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-vesa (2:2.3.2-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-vmware (2:13.0.0-makson1~raring1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-core (3:1.12.4+git20121105-makson2~raring1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

Output on reinstalling -

```
hmehra@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
libxatracker1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
The following NEW packages will be installed:
xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,228 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,757 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main xserver-xorg-core amd64   2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 [1,228 kB]
Fetched 1,228 kB in 1s (633 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-core.
(Reading database ... 410842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.15.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking xserver-xorg-core (2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-core (2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bug because in 14.04 these options are available via the GUI.

This is a possible solution for you, view the original answer here [Enable Edge And Two Finger Scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372988/enable-both-two-finger-scrolling-and-edge-scrolling-permanently)

Quite simple create a script using gedit or a document writer

First open `gedit` and copy and paste the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Save the file as `scrolling.sh` in your `~/bin` directory

change the permissions to be able to run it as program open terminal `CTRL + ALT + T` run this command:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/scrolling
```

search for `Startup Applications` in Dash, and open it then set up scrolling to run when ubuntu starts up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the gpointing-device-settings, it worked on my Asus.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

It runs from the GUI interface, you will find it in your applications just search for pointing devices, the icon is just a mouse but the app is for touchpad.  Has a separate scrolling tab.

Or, from command line

```
gpointing-device-settings
```

Actually faster response on my system.

**To fix broken packages.**

Try
Code:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package list.
Then
Code:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up any partial packages.
Then
Code:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean up the apt cache.
Code:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will clean up any unneeded dependencies.
If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.
Code:

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq <package name>
```

Change package name to the real name of course.

Then

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This final step is to be sure you have no remaining broken packages.

You should be able to install your packages now.

**To completely remove xserver-xorg and re-install do the following.**

Remove existing xorg using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
```

Install xorg using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

Reconfigure xorg using the following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then attempt to install multitouch again.

Comment: The gpointing-device-settings did not resolve the problem. Still the scrolling does not work.

Comment: Try to install sudo apt-get update then sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch

Comment: On installing xserver-xorg-input-multitouch I receive the following error -

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-multitouch : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @hmehra see additional edits in answer, for fixing broken packages.

Comment: I tried the edit but still the problem persists. Please advise

Comment: Please run "sudo apt-get install -f" and post the complete results.

Comment: Please see the edit and respond.

Comment: See the bottom part of the answer, in bold type To remove then re-install the Xserver-xorg then you will need to attempt your multitouch as before.

Comment: The problem still persists. The multitouch package cannot be installed because it depends on xorg-input-abi20.

Comment: Please do this "sudo apt-get autoremove xserver-xorg-core" and post the result. Then, "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core" Please post both results.

Comment: You might want to use the Synaptic Package Manager to perform all of these tasks.  It does a good job of managing dependencies and also provides explanation about each package.  It will show you what is currently installed.

Comment: I was able to install the multitouch package but the problem is still present. Please let me know if you have some other suggestions

Comment: did you autoremove the xserver-xorg-core package, see third comment above this one.

Comment: I removed those packages. Please see the edit on my initial post

Comment: There is a complete explanation of how to control the touchpad features through the install you now have located at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad .  There are many command line parameters you have the ability to control.  This information is too much to post, but it may help you to solve the scrolling issue.  AT LEAST, we were able to get the packages installed so that you will be able to get control of your features.

Comment: I am unable to run synclient. I receive the following error. Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded? Any suggestions?

Comment: Be sure to read all of the instructional information.  There is a section an making sure your touchpad is detected thru synaptics and more on being sure your synaptics config is being used.  I think you answer is there but you need to take the time to go through the entire process.

Comment: If I have helped in finding a solution please show as solved are vote up my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just went into system settings and selected "natural scrolling" under the mouse and trackpad options.  While the trackpad does not react to the slider bars on the side and bottom, it DOES scroll appropriately when I put 2 fingers on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling two finger scroll. Mine worked perfectly after that as the new 14.04 is prepared to modern Synaptic Touchpads with that feature enabled.

Comment: I am unable to disable the two finger scroll. Under the settings, I don't have that option available

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my fujitsu laptop. Finally i solved the issue by replacing some code in

```
/etc/default/grub
```

This is my modified file looks.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0       
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0    
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true       
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10    
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"       
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""   
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux"
```

then run command

```
sudo update grub
```

Probably it will help you out.

Comment: You need to remove fist line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing "Pointing Devices" from Ubuntu Software Centre, this worked for me on my sony vaio with Alps pointing device , and now both edge scrolling is working perfectly.

i am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS