# Ubuntu 14.04 Touch pad froze on restart - fixed it but scrolling is still not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, mouse-scroll

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty version. I installed APM Planner yesterday and upon restarting my computer, my touchpad stopped working. (frozen but buttons working)

In order to fix the issue, I followed this thread: ([Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working/262364#262364)) and my frozen touchpad started working. However, the two finger scrolling is still not working. I saw this thread to fix it: [Enable both: two finger scrolling and edge scrolling permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372988/enable-both-two-finger-scrolling-and-edge-scrolling-permanently), however, I am not able to make my bash file "executable". I am wondering if I am following the right path, can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it myself. I edited the bash file and added

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

this line was edited somehow and was reflected when I rebooted my computer! So my mouse scroll works as before now.