# One user has two finger scrolling the other does not

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm trying to troubleshoot my husband's computer, running 18.04. My gnome shell on his machine has two finger scrolling that works just fine. His gnome shell "mouse and touchpad" settings are identical to mine, and two finger scrolling is definitely on, but two finger scrolling only works for me.

I've been switching between his login and mine to test the behavior and settings -- so I've tested this with the same two fingers. I can scroll fine with two fingers in my shell but not in his shell.

What would interfere with two-finger scrolling for only one user on a machine, but not all users?

Comment: If you log in as him and perform 2 finger scrolling identical to the way that you behave on your user, what happens?  This situation?

Comment: I noticed there is another thread here that may help. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad/373134). It appears to provide the command to enable two finger scrolling from the command line. `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1 >> ~/.config/scroll-touchpad ` + some permissions that need to be set on a `config` file.

Comment: @eyoung100 Updated question so it's clear. I've tested this behavior multiple times with my own two fingers.